Why is writing "however" to join two clauses wrong e.g. …, however, …?
Why is option B incorrect?

In botany, the term “resurrection plant” refers to any species of plant that seems to come back to life after appearing fully withered and dead. Resurrection plants do not truly return from the dead, ____ are simply exhibiting an adaptation that allows them to survive in very dry conditions for extended periods.

Which choice completes the text so that it conforms to the conventions of Standard English?

A. however they
B. however, they
C. however. They
D. however but they

According to Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary, the adverb however can be positioned at the start of a new sentence in order to show contract with a previous statement; e.g. We thought the figures were correct. However, we have now discovered some errors.  And in mid-sentence enclosed by commas; e.g. He was feeling bad. He went to work, however, and tried to concentrate. This would suggest that B is also an acceptable answer. Why is option B incorrect?


Yes, you can use however at the end of a clause for contrast. Though, unfortunately, and sadly would work the same way, surprisingly:  "Plants do not truly return from the dead, though, they are simply exhibiting an adaptation..."

The close reason makes no sense, because the correct option C and the incorrect option B both put "however" at the end of an independent clause.

@alphabet So the question reverts to the ungrammaticality of [most] run-on sentences, covered in depth on ELU.

@EdwinAshworth Doesn't matter, IMHO; the stated close reason was still incorrect given the text of the question.

The question should be closed for low quality. It has nothing to do with the words - it's a punctuation thing. The premise is entirely wrong.

The previous question deals with the acceptability of using 'however' at the end of an independent clause. Run-on sentences have been dealt with ad nauseam. The 'however, they' answer is correctly labelled unacceptable as a run-on sentence (most are).

It's certainly possible to end a sentence with "however". It is often used to indicate a transition of some sort, affixed to the end of the sentence that begins the transition.
The Corpus of Contemporary American English has lots of results (8906) for "however" at the end of a sentence. Most are in blogs or transcribed speech (in fairness, a lot of all COCA content is from blogs).
New York Times blog: "Getting people to the Red Planet hasn't been a success story, however." (Following a discussion of unmanned probes.)
Patheos blog: "Something like 7 States have a requirement for god belief in their State constitutions. That is unconstitutional under the federal constitution however."
NBC News, apparently a transcript of a discussion: "O'Reilly, Coulter, Schultz, Maddow, Limbaugh, etc., are opinion programs. If anyone thinks they are objective news programs, they are getting their 'news' from the wrong source. The opinion shows are just that, opinion! Fox News is a different thing, however. They promote themselves as 'fair and balanced', yet they have a clearly conservative bias."
Daily Kos blog: "What they say and what they do are two different things, however."
Jewish Policy Center blog: "Dictatorships understand the Western psyche, however."

Thanks for the reply. Do suggest the grammatical structure which makes option B incorrect.
